# Why is ChangeListener never used locally?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, changelistener

I am not sure why I get the warning 'The method tabChanged(ChangeEvent) from the type new ChangeListener(){} is never used locally'

```
private void setUpTabbedPane() {
            this.tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            this.tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
            String titles[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

            for (int i = 0, n = titles.length; i < n; i++) {
                addTabs(this.tabbedPane, titles[i]);
            }

            this.tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                public void tabChanged(ChangeEvent ev) {
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, something went wrong.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### You have declared an 'orphaned' method

As the warning says, you have declared a method tabChanged() within the ChangeListener that isn't referenced anywhere, and will never ever be called by anyone.

If you want your code to be run whenever change happens, you have to override the *stateChanged* method of the ChangeListener (as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html)
 instead of declaring a new method as you have done now.

Just changing the name from tabChanged() to stateChanged() IMHO should be sufficient to make this code work.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `@Override` annotation, which would also catch such 'orphaned' methods.